Why does gradle8.7 generate a checkstyleMain folder in the build\tmp folder after building?
When using Gradle 8.7, after executing Gradle build, a checkstyleMain(empty) folder will be generated in the project build folder
same checkstyle configuration, using gradle 4.5.1 will not
I want to know what version of Gradle will generate this folder
Why is this folder generated and what does it do?
I tried to search in the official doc, but couldn't find it
